# Selecting combinations of classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to load divs with different combinations of classes from an external file using jquery's load function and I have some trouble grouping them correctly.

```
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1");   // loads all divs with class1
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1.class2");   // loads all divs with class1 and class2
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1,.class2");   // loads all divs with class1 and all divs with class2
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1.class2,.class3");   // loads all divs with class1 and class2 and all divs with class3
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1,.class2.class3");   // loads all divs with class1 and all divs with class2 and class3
```

I would like to know how to load divs with (class1 or class2) AND class3. Something like:

```
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html {.class1,.class2}.class3");
```

I have tried grouping with (),[] and {} but none of it seemed to work.

My external file would look something like this:

```
<div class="class1">not selected</div>
<div class="class1 class2">not selected</div>
<div class="class2 class3">selected</div>
<div class="class1 class2 class3">selected</div>
<div class="class1 class3">selected</div>
<div class="class3">not selected</div>
...etc
```

Basically any combination of classes would be possible.

Comment: So it's a little unclear. From you example, which divs would you want to select? You want to select divs with either (`class1` and `class3`) or (`class2` and `class3`)? Is that correct?

Comment: So I edited to make it clear that with your example you'd only selected the third and forth divs. Please correct it if that is wrong.

Comment: I also added another example that should be selected if I am understanding your requirements correctly

Comment: Thank you! This is how I meant it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#somediv").load("somefile.html .class1.class3,.class2.class3");
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Will take anything that has class 3 and either class1 or class2

Comment: Personnal question : why use comma between item 2 and 3, and not betweeen item 1 and 2 ?

Comment: it is for enumeration... Select .class1.class3 then select also .class2.class3

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem indeed. It would require a bit more code though for longer sequences like  {class1 OR class2 OR class3}AND{classA OR classB OR classC}AND{classX OR classY OR classZ}

Comment: @Leuven: Yes, you'd have to expand it out, which would quickly become impractical. At which point you might be better off selecting the groups separately and processing them in a loop. Or you might want to think about your requirements and see if there isn't a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, I can process them in a loop as well if it needs to be done. I was just wondering if there is a way to avoid this by parenthesizing.